# Enumerate field from existing records in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0, enumeration

I work with cakePHP and have database table with 3 columns: ID, Name, OrderNo

- **ID** is the primary key which is defined as autoincrement field and contains a number.
- **Name** is a user given value
- **OrderNo** contains a numeric value which is used for sorting SELECT result (ORDER BY ...)

Now, the OrderNo Field is needed because the user have the right, change the order. So far, no problem. If the record on the 4 place on the result should switch the position with the record on place 8, I only flip the value in the field OrderNo and the next result will return the new ordered list.

But now, there is a situation where simply updating will result in a long execution time when I've many records:

When I delete a record, a "place" will be freed. I want close the gap and want enumerate all fields starting with 0.

Sample records;

```
ID, Name,  OrderNo
==================
 1, Name1, 5
 2, Name2, 4
 3, Name3, 3
 4, Name4, 2
 5, Name5, 1
```

I remove ID 3 which results in

```
ID, Name,  OrderNo
==================
 1, Name1, 5
 2, Name2, 4
 4, Name4, 2
 5, Name5, 1
```

Which should be

```
ID, Name,  OrderNo
==================
 1, Name1, 4
 2, Name2, 3
 4, Name4, 2
 5, Name5, 1
```

Currently I would loop all existing records (sorted by OrderNo) and would write the field OrderNo with a value which I would increase every round but this solution isn't really efficient. I tested it with 5000 records and it tooks 40 seconds to finish.

Is there maybe a cakePHP solution based on sql syntax which can do that job much more faster?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the tree behavior is what you looking for. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html

Comment: Have you maybe a example which show how it would work? I see that it could fit to my problem (reorder function for example), I just no concrete idea how specially.

Comment: You can build the tree like it's done in the category example in the cakephp book. use ['parent_id'] = null  if you just need the order, but not the tree behavior. 
After deleting a row in your table recover the tree with $this->Category->recover();

Comment: I try some things implement tree behaviour to my existing code base but doesn't have success. I focused my search for a possible solution to a sql query which should be the most efficient method modify a big set of records and found a suitable solution:

`set @i=0; UPDATE message SET orderno = (@i:=@i+1) ORDER BY orderno`

It is very fast and do what I want!